# how to install wowza for android using react native

Tags: android, react-native, installation, wowza

My build fails after installing wowza for android. RN version is 0.44. I followed [this manual installation](https://github.com/medlmobileenterprises/react-native-wowza-gocoder), but it fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-wowza-gocoder'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-wowza-gocoder:_debugPublishCopy'.
  > Could not find com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android:com.wowza.gocoder.sdk:1.0.
    Required by:
           ******Project:react-native-wowza-gocoder:unspecified
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, figured it out myself.

Install react-native-wowza-gocoder and the follow below -

Android

1. Open up android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java
2. Add import com.rngocoder.RNWowzaBroadcasterPackage; to the imports at the top of the file
   Add new RNWowzaBroadcasterPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method
3. Append the following lines to android/settings.gradle:
   include ':react-native-wowza-gocoder'
   project(':react-native-wowza-gocoder').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-wowza-gocoder/android')
4. Insert the following lines inside the dependencies block in android/app/build.gradle:
   compile project(':react-native-wowza-gocoder')

Post installation Android

1. After obtaining WowzaGoCoderSDK aar file, add it to your nodemodules/react-native-wowza-gocoder/android/libs (create libs if needed), it's also need to add the dependency on your main app, add the aar file to libs directory(create it if needed) -> /android/app/libs
   2.Then add the following lines to both build.gradle files, on nodemodules/react-native-wowza-gocoder and app/build.gradle
   repositories {
   flatDir {
   dirs 'libs'
   }
   }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// The GoCoder SDK library dependency declaration
 compile 'com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android:com.wowza.gocoder.sdk:1.0@aar'

// List additional dependencies here...
}

3. http://www.wowza.com/resources/gocodersdk/docs/1.0/intro-installation/